# Bootstrap collapsiable menu doesn't open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am learning bootstrap from w3schools.

There is an example of menu that turns to collapsiable menu when screen is small: [W3Schools Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse)

I have literally copied it one to one but it isn't working, no idea why (the bootstrap itself is working fine).

What exactly happens is that menu links hide under a button but it doesnt open when I click it.

Plus I would like to add there `justify-content-center` the `<nav>` but as I can see it breakes even the menu in this w3schools snippet after adding this class name to the `<nav>`

Could you guys please help me out on this?

Here is my entire page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">

       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
           <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>

    </nav>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the all of the required JavaScript files for Bootstrap to function properly, this include bootstrap.js, jquery and popper. Be sure to include this code just before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/uwzm82do/

Comment: Damn I should have predicted that. Thank you very much! Do you know maybe why justify-content-center isnt working with this?

Comment: @divHelper11 if you're trying to center align the links on the navbar you need to add 'justify-content-center' to the div that is wrapping them. See the link below: https://jsfiddle.net/uwzm82do/3/